# DataGrid, reset ScrollViewer to left hand side

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

Is there a way to reset the Horizontal ScrollViewer of the DataGrid back to all the way on the left?  I have it hooked up to another control where plots get refreshed.  It would be nice if the associated DataGrid gets reset also and has the scrollViewer all the way on the left.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the `ScrollViewer` directly, but if you look at the Visual Tree with snoop you can see that is looks like `DataGrid`, `Border`, `ScrollViewer`

[image]

So to scroll the `DataGrid` to the left, you can use the following extension method (or just use a normal method)

```
public static class DataGridExtensions
{
    public static void ScrollToLeft(this DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        Border border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid, 0) as Border;
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
        scrollViewer.ScrollToLeftEnd();
    }
}
```

Call it like this

```
dataGrid.ScrollToLeft();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to ensure that the first cell of the selected row is visible.

```
    if (dataGrid.SelectedItem != null)
        dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.SelectedItem, dataGrid.Columns[0]);
```